# table scheme definiation it this way that insert duplicate into another table

Tags: index, mysql-5.5, unique-constraint

I have a table in which there is a column name with `SP varchar(10) NOT NULL`. I want that column always to be unique so i created unique index on that column . My table schema as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblspmaster` (
  `CSN` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SP` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `FileImportedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `AMZFileName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CasperBatch` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BatchProcessedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ExpiryDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FCCity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LocationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CSN`),
  UNIQUE KEY `SP` (`SP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10000000000 ;
```

Now i want that if anybody tries to insert duplicate record then that record should be inserted into a secondary table name `tblDuplicate`.

I have gone through this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry but i am not sure that instead of

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,200) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=200;
```

can i insert duplicate row into another table ?

what changes needed to be done in main table scheme or index column ?

**Note : Data will be inserted by importing excel or csv files.**